# How to convert string value to int in Json field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to this kind of situation.
I have a column in which I have json data.

[image: Column of table]

What am trying to do is to remove the " **double quotes** from all the `id` values.

For example `[{"id":"5","position":1}]`

Should become `[{"id":5,"position":1}]`

I have tried this query
`update products set category_ids = JSON_SET(category_ids, "$.id", REPLACE("$.id", '"', '')) where id = any_row_id;`

But the query is getting implemented successfully and no changes are reflecting.

Comment: Provide sample data as textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (columns `id` and `category_ids` is enough), the picture is not useful.

Comment: Parse (use JSON_TABLE() function) then reconstruct with needed datatype. Also you may use textual processing and use REGEXP_REPLACE() function.

Comment: @akina actually it was made using laravel migration. When I checked the structure of this table, `category_ids` is *varchar*, Also Please if you could provide me some example of what you suggested

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @akina If you could please provide a solution then

Comment: Before json_encoding the array, cast the id to int: `$arr['id'] = (integer)$arr['id'];`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change the type of value in a JSON object like this (note: example is from MariaDB 10.6):

```
select
  json_object_col as original_object,
  JSON_REPLACE(
    json_object_col,
    "$.id",
    CAST(JSON_VALUE(json_object_col, "$.id") AS INTEGER)
  ) as updated_object

from (
  select JSON_OBJECT("id", "11") as json_object_col
) input;
```

This produces:

```
original_object  |  updated_object
---------------------------------
{"id": "11"}     |  {"id": 11}
```

However, `JSON_REPLACE` function does not support wildcard paths needed to replace all elements of the array.

To do that, you would likely need to either:

- Use `JSON_TABLE` function to split the JSON array into multiple rows, and then use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` to merge the rows back into a single JSON array
- Create a custom function that iterates the array, similar to: [MariaDB updating json attribute across array in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59053411/mariadb-updating-json-attribute-across-array-in-json)